# хорош ли такой подход в архитектуре проекта?

Tags: node.js, шаблоны-проектирования

В своих проектах API - я использую паттерн Controller -> Service -> Model. В простых проектах достаточно описать все функций в одном файле.
user.controller.js

```
const ApiError = require('../error/ApiError');
const yup = require('yup');
...

exports.login = (req, res, next) => {...}
exports.signup = (req, res, next) => {...}
exports.getInfo = (req, res, next) => {...}
exports.changePassword = (req, res, next) => {...}
```

Но когда проект развивается, то соответственно растет код, и хранить все в 1 файле становится неудобно. Например когда файл состоит из 500 строк кода и нужно изменить где то 1 строчку кода, то приходится скроллить вниз, что очень неудобно.
Я решил, а что если каждую функцию разделить на под файлы и подключать в итоге все в index.js

```
controllers/user/
- index.js (Единая точка входа для всех функций);
- login.js;
- signup.js
...
```

и получается что то вроде 
controllers/user/login.js

```
const ApiError = require('../error/ApiError');
const yup = require('yup');
...

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {...}
```

controllers/user/index.js

```
const login = require('./login');
const signup = require('./signup');
...

module.exports = {
 login,
 signup 
};
```

Теперь намного удобней редактировать функций, и все они хранятся в одной точке. 
Как вы считаете мой подход к проектированию нормальный или есть что то похожее?

Comment: нормальный :) Но я не спец в этом, это мое субъективное мнение. Вот статья на тему https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/7.1.php

Comment: *"..то приходится скроллить вниз, что очень неудобно."* - для такого есть команды аля `ctrl + d (перейти на строку)`, либо `ctrl + f (поиск)`

Comment: и что вы каждую функцию будете выносить в отдельный файл? как-то не очень удобно, много файлов будет, запутаюсь. С одной стороны для меня это оверкил, а с другой если файл действительно буде оченьььь огромный, то может и есть смысл разделить на несколько подфайлов и поделить функции по логике что к чему

Comment: @entithat насчет ctrl +f/d , у меня на практике были случаи, когда нужно одновременно менять несколько функций ( все писал в одном файле) и каждый раз нажимать такую комбинацию тоже неудобно становится, а если нужно будет просматривать функций параллельно? Да я понимаю современные IDE позволяют разделять окна и можно просматривать 1 файл в разных участках кода, но а если работа в команде, и соответственно другие программисты и не додумаются так сделать или еще какие обстоятельства. И по сей день пока другого решения, как своего разделять функций на файлы я не нашел.

Comment: та впринципе тут кому как удобно. если у вас функция на 20 строк, то я не вижу смысла выносить ее в отдельный файл.

Comment: @entithat да тут вы правы конечно, но наверняка кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, и возможно есть какое то единое решение или соглашение о кодирований.

Comment: ну поздравляю, вы изобрели модули, собственно `exports`/`import`/`require` для этого существуют. В чем ваш вопрос то?

Answer (score 1):

Я пришел к такому выводу, что все таки лучше использовать архитектуру, которая была описана мною в вопросе. 
Пример, когда это вам поможет:

- Удобно работать с кодом. Понятно что и где находится.
- Ваш проект всегда должен иметь возможность расширяться. Соответственно хранить код все в 1 файле уже неправильно. Если это Rest Api ? - то часто бывает, что меняется бизнес логика и появляются роутеры вида /api/v1/users, /api/v2/users.
- С большим кол-ом кода другие программисты не будут мучаться.

Comment: в принципе вопрос деления файлов на части - это нормально, выносить куда-то общие моменты и т.п. но вопрос в целом холиваный, тут главное знать меру, если Вам удобно - это главное, если работаете в комманде ей должно быть удобно. Но честно говоря я не очень-то долюбливаю проекты с 1к файлов хотя такое на серьезных проектах не редкость.